# Partial Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

So I have an interface -

```
public interface GenericTranslator <From, To> {
    To translate(From from);
}
```

and have a class that implements it

```
public class TimeToStringTranslator implements GenericTranslator <Time, String>  {
    String translate(Time time) { ... }
}
```

But I now want to have an abstract layer where input type `From` is `Time`

```
// an abstract class with partial generic defined
public abstract class AbstractTimeTranslator<Time, To> implements GenericTranslator<Time, To> {

    @Override
    To translate(Time time) { 
       doSomething();

       return translateTime(time);
    }

    protected abstract To translateTime(Time time);
}

// concrete class
public class TimeToStringTranslator extends AbstractTimeTranslator<Time, String> {
    String translateTime(Time time) { .... }
}
```

Is it possible in Java? I tried, Java treats `Time` as a generic name in `AbstractTimeTranslator`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `Time` is an actual type argument instead of another generic type parameter, then you should not declare `Time` as a generic type parameter in the class definition of `AbstractTimeTranslator`; just use it as a type argument in the `implements` clause.

This only defines the `To` type parameter in this class.

```
abstract class AbstractTimeTranslator<To> implements GenericTranslator<Time, To> {
```

Consequently, you only need to supply one type argument in the `extends` clause of the concrete subclass.

```
class TimeToStringTranslator extends AbstractTimeTranslator<String> {
```

Comment: I can't help feeling like this problem probably would have been avoided if the convention of single-letter type arguments had been followed.